# Python Conditional Split

Tags: python, split

Given this string:

```
s = '01/03/1988 U/9 Mi\n08/19/1966 ABC\nDEF\n12/31/1999 YTD ABC'
```

I want to split it on each new record (which starts with a date) like this:

```
['01/03/1988 U/9 Mi', '08/19/1966 ABC\nDEF', '12/31/1999 YTD ABC']
```

Notice the extra new line delimiter between ABC and DEF? That's the challenge I'm having. I want to preserve it without a split there.
I'm thinking I need to conditionally split on any delimiter of these:

```
['01/', '02/','03/', '04/', '05/', '06/', '07/', '08/', '09/', '10/', '11/', '12/']
```

Is there an easy way to use `re.findall` this way or is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split on the new line that is followed by a date with a lookahead. Something like:

```
import re

s = '01/03/1988 U/9 Mi\n08/19/1966 ABC\nDEF\n12/31/1999 YTD ABC'
re.split(r'\n(?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})', s)

# ['01/03/1988 U/9 Mi', '08/19/1966 ABC\nDEF', '12/31/1999 YTD ABC']
```

You may be able to simplify to just a newline followed by 2 digits depending on your data: `r'\n(?=\d{2})'`

Answer (score 1):

Use regex instead.

#### code

```py
import re
s = '01/03/1988 U/9 Mi\n08/19/1966 ABC\nDEF\n12/31/1999 YTD ABC'
chunks = re.compile(r'[\n](?=\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d)').split(s)
print(chunks)
```

#### output

```
['01/03/1988 U/9 Mi', '08/19/1966 ABC\nDEF', '12/31/1999 YTD ABC']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also match a more specific date like format without lookarounds.

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:19|20)\d\d\b.*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:0[1-9]|1[012])` Match a month number from 01 - 12
- `/` Match literally
- `(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` Match a number 01 - 31
- `/` Match literally
- `(?:19|20)\d\d` Match either 19 or 20 and 2 digits (Or just 4 digits `\d{4}`)
- `\b.*` A word boundary and match the rest of the line
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oLmQIb/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fyNU3A)

Example code

```
import re

s = '01/03/1988 U/9 Mi\n08/19/1966 ABC\nDEF\n12/31/1999 YTD ABC'
regex = r'^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(?:19|20)\d\d\b.*$'
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['01/03/1988 U/9 Mi', '08/19/1966 ABC', '12/31/1999 YTD ABC']
```